# insertar muchos registros PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Muy buenos días, tengo una duda, ¿existe una manera de insertar por partes en php? es que tengo que registrar como  3 mil registros por día en mysql desde php, y muchas veces se corta la conexión por el tiempo de espera y no puedo aumentar el tiempo espera por cuestiones de hardware.

actualizacion: brindo el codigo, en resumen lo que hago es crear un arreglo con los datos a insertar, y luego lo pongo en un foreach para que lo recorra e inserte los datos

```
foreach ($tickets_hoy as $value){
            $productos_de_hoy = $coll->distinct("detalle.producto",["ticket" => $value]);
            $sucursales_de_hoy = $coll->distinct("tienda",["ticket" => $value]);

            $insertar = "INSERT INTO prueba (producto, ticket) VALUES ($productos_de_hoy,$value)";
       
            if ($db->query($insertar) ==  true) {
             echo "";
            } else {
             echo "error".$insertar."<br>". $database->error;
            }
        }
```

Comment: ¿Como lo estas haciendo ahora? mysqli? pdo?  insert? uno a uno? todos a la vez?  en un bucle? Pega tu código y te podremos ayudar mejor, sino vamos a jugar a las adivinanzas y es posible que todos perdamos el tiempo así

Comment: Agradeceríamos que nos brindaras tu código para poder ayudarte, saludos.

Comment: se puede pero necesitamos los modulos o partes de estos de lo que tienes para analizarlos y canalizar la sugerencia.

Comment: No intentes poner el código en un comentario. Hazlo en la propia pregunta pulsando el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la misma pregunta. Eso lo puedes hacer las veces que necesites para agregar la información que te vayan pidiendo en los comentarios para mejorar la pregunta y obtener mejores ayudas, gracias.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Y si vuelcas todos los `insert` en una variable (cada uno terminado con `;`) y luego haces una [multi_query](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php)?  Pierdes un poco el control de los inserts, pues si te peta uno no sabras cual es, pero ganas tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: ¿De donde obtienes los datos que quieres insertar?.
En el caso de que lo obtengas de un excel o un archivo similar te recomendaría que la información que deseas insertar la captes con javascript y el foreach lo realices tambien con javascript de esta manera no ejecutarás la función de insert php de manera continua por lo que no tendrás problemas con el tiempo de ejecución de php.

Comment: si revisas SQL veras que puedes hacer algo como `INSERT INTO prueba (producto, ticket) VALUES (), (), (), (),()`. puedes preparar los parentesis en un bucle, para generar solo una insert con todos esos valores. Ademas, si son muchos, tambien puedes usar `array_chunk` para recorrer el array a trozos, e ir  rellenando segun un tamaño (haciendo por ej, 10 o 20 inserts). Echa un vistazo en https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-chunk.php y en https://www.srcodigofuente.es/sql-insert-multiple

Comment: los obtengo de una consulta de mongo, primero realizo una consulta de mongo y los datos los extraigo de ahi, para luego guardarlos en un arreglo y luego insertarlos, pero me diste al idea con javascritp, intentare ese modo, gracias

Comment: [Según la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html) la forma más eficaz de insertar grandes cantidades de datos es usando `LOAD DATA`, la segunda es la que te indica @Jakala en su comentario. Ahora bien, hay otro aspecto a considerar aquí: **la seguridad**. Te recomiendo que des prioridad a la seguridad, y luego a la eficacia. Un código eficaz, pero que permita *inyección SQL*, es una bomba de tiempo y cualquier día te llevas una desagradable sorpresa. Una opción interesante para tu caso podría ser crear un archivo con los datos y llevar la inserción ...

Comment: ... a un nivel más bajo: la consola, programando un script que lea ese archivo y ejecute una inserción segura, usando un procedimiento almacenado programado en el servidor de base de datos. Tendrías resueltos los dos problemas básicos: la seguridad y la eficacia.